# How do I reconcile these three ayat on the foods available in hell?

Tags: quran, jahannam

According to Surah Al Haqq, the only food in Hell is the washing of wounds:

> "Nor hath he any food except the corruption from the washing of wounds," ([69:36](https://legacy.quran.com/69/36))

According to Surah Gashiya, it is dari:

> "No food will there be for them but a bitter Dhari" ([88:6](https://legacy.quran.com/88/6))

And Surah Waqia mentions the fruit of Zaqqum:

> "Ye will surely taste of the Tree of Zaqqum." ([56:52](https://legacy.quran.com/56/52))

Insofar as the Qur'an is considered perfect and without error, how are these three ayat reconciled with each other?

Answer (score 3):

They can be reconciled as follows:

- غسلين and ضريع and زقوم are different names of the same thing, or one of them contains the other.

  > عن الضحاك ، في قوله:{غسلين} [الحاقة: 36] قال: هو الضريع، شجرة يأكل منها أهل النار
  >
  > Dhahak ibn Muzahim  said regarding غسلين that it is ضريع a tree from which the people of Hell eat
  >
  > <sup>— [Ibn Abid Dunya](https://shamela.ws/book/13128/88#p1)</sup>

  > عن سعيد بن جبير إلا من ضريع قال: الزقوم
  >
  > Saeed ibn Jubair said regarding ضريع that it is زقوم
  >
  > <sup>— [Ibn Abi Hatim](https://shamela.ws/book/8658/3411#p1)</sup>
- There are multiple levels of Hell and in them people have different states of punishment; see e.g. [15:44](http://quran.com/15/44), [4:145](http://quran.com/4/145), [40:46](http://quran.com/40/46)

  If the three things are distinct then the meaning is that in one state the people will consume only غسلين, while in another they will consume only ضريع, and in another they will consume زقوم

  > قال الكلبي: الضريع في درجة ليس فيها غيره، والزقوم في درجة أخرى
  >
  > Kalbi said: ضريع is in a level in which there is nothing else and زقوم is in another level
  >
  > <sup>— [Qurtubi](https://shamela.ws/book/20855/7220)</sup>
- In these verses the word إلا is not used as an exception but in the sense of 'rather', similar to how it is used in [20:2-3](https://quran.com/20/2-3), [88:22-24](https://quran.com/88/22-24), [56:25-26](https://quran.com/56/25-26) etc.

  The meaning is that the people of Hell will not have any actual food at all, *rather* they will eat X.  This is compatible with eating multiple things which are not from the genus of real food such as what some of the exegetes have claimed to be the meaning of ضريع (a bitter poisonous thorny plant) and غسلين (discharge of wounds) - they are all not food.

References: [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://shamela.ws/book/20855/7220),  [Tafsir al-Razi](https://shamela.ws/book/23635/5993#p12)

Comment: Jazakallah, sister. Great Answer! May Allah reward you for your services at Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following article:-

https://www.call-to-monotheism.com/concerning_the_food_for_the_inhabitants_of_hell__by_ansar_al__adl

https://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-about-islam/many-contradictions-quran/